# Unable to destroy monster after negating its effects

Tags: yu-gi-oh

So, 10 minutes ago I played with friend in Dueling Nexus. I used [Infinite Impermanence](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Impermanence) on his [Number 101: Silent Honor ARK](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Number_101:_Silent_Honor_ARK) and he wasn't able to detach two materials in order to take one of my special summoned monsters. However, he could actually prevent destruction by detaching one material.

I activated Infinite Impermanence, then chained with [Torrential Tribute](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Torrential_Tribute); I assume that the problem comes from that both effects are in the same Chain Link. Could this be the case?

Answer (score 1):

> I activated Infinite Impermanence, then chained with Torrential Tribute; I assume that the problem comes from that both effects are in the same Chain Link. Could this be the case?

I see several problems here:

1. **Activating Torrential Tribute as a chain to Infinite Impermanence is not a valid move ([Missed Timing](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Missing_the_timing)).**

   The text of Torrential Tribute specifies that you can activate it *when* a monster(s) is summoned (emphasis mine):

   > **When a monster(s) is Summoned**: Destroy all monsters on the field.

   This means that **to activate Torrential Tribute, the last thing that must have happened is a monster(s) being summoned**. In your case, the last thing that happened in the Chain was the activation of Infinite Impermanence, so you can't chain Torrential Tribute to that (see TT's [card rulings](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Torrential_Tribute)).
2. **Let's suppose for a moment that you *could* have activated TT that way...:**

   In this scenario, the reason why Number 101 was not destroyed was indeed due to the chain, specifically the Chain resolution order. *When resolving Chains, they take effect in "reverse order" as they were activated (the Chain Stack)*:

   - Chain 0: Summoning Number 101
   - Chain 1: Infinite Impermanence to No.101
   - Chain 2: Torrential Tribute activated (if it where possible move)

   Resolving...:

   - Chain 2: All monsters on the field are destroyed. **As Number 101 still has it's effects enabled he can save himself by detaching an XYZ material.**
   - Chain 1: Number 101 effects are negated by Infinite Impermanence

---

Next time, to successfully (and legally) negate and destroy Number 101 you should activate TT and II in *reverse order*: **Summon->Torrential Tribute->Infinite Impermanence** so it resolves **Negate->Destroy.**

Comment: This is incorrect. Torrential Tribute can be activated anywhere in the chain after a Successful Summon. It misses timing only if that Summon wasn't the last thing to occur in the chain the Summon occured in (if it occurred in one). Point (2) is the correct answer.

Comment: Hey @Shuri2060 uhmm, actually that is what I meant: it misses timing if the summon was not the last thing... mind telling me on what part I could have screwed up?

Comment: @Shuri2060 please, refer to this [Torrential tribute ruling](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Torrential_Tribute) where you will see that indeed the last thing to happen must be a summon. OP can't chain his own TT to Infinite Impermanence... it should have been the other way round (like detailed in point 2).

Comment: Not sure which part of the wikia rulings u are referring to, but it is well known that TT can be activated as CL 2 or higher. It misses timing in an example like - CL 1: upstart goblin CL 2: Call of the Haunted. The last thing to happen when the chain resolves is the gain in LP.

Comment: 'Last thing to happen' does not include actions occurring in the current chain that is being built.

Answer (score 0):

I take it the situation is:

After the successful Xyz Summon of Number 101: Silent Honor ARK,

CL 1: Infinite Impermanence (targ SHArk)
CL 2: Torrential Tribute

---

The above chain is perfectly legal. Resolve it backwards.

Torrential Tribute destroys all monsters on field. SHArk can apply its continuous effect to prevent its destruction.

Infinite Impermanence negates SHArk's effects (if it is still on field).

---

Note sure what you mean by 'he wasn't able to detach two materials in order to take one of my special summoned monsters', though.